# Zookeeper standalone or via hbase?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, system-installation

I completed a multi node Hadoop 2.7 installation (1 master 3 slave) on AWS - Ubuntu ( not EMR) and planning to go ahead for the next step (hbase, hive, pig, flume, sqoop.....)
**Question**: should I install zookeeper as a standalone and then hbase or should I install hbase and use native zookeeper already integrated in hbase

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always install a standalone Zookeeper ensemble for HBase when used for production. (you'll also need Zookeeper if/when you want to run multiple HDFS NameNode for high availability)

- an HBase committer

Comment: Thanks Lars - Valid point and I will keep this in the back of my head when working on a production project. Since I am using the AWS free tier as a fun playground and just configured 1 namenode, having an integrated Zookeeper sounds a reasonable and easier choice to start with (feel free to comment if I am misunderstanding your views),